# Reactive Kafka and many partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, project-reactor

Does number of Kafka partitions matter for Reactive Kafka Receiver or the efficency is the same as with one Kafka partition (as the reactive receiver anyway uses one thread (if so))?

Answer (score 1):

According to sources ([1](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/8436f5ca887898b3738df41deb973d1a58d5881e/src/main/java/reactor/kafka/receiver/internals/KafkaSchedulers.java#L39), [2](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/8436f5ca887898b3738df41deb973d1a58d5881e/src/main/java/reactor/kafka/receiver/internals/ConsumerHandler.java#L108), [3](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/8436f5ca887898b3738df41deb973d1a58d5881e/src/main/java/reactor/kafka/receiver/internals/DefaultKafkaReceiver.java#L137) and [4](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/8436f5ca887898b3738df41deb973d1a58d5881e/src/main/java/reactor/kafka/receiver/internals/DefaultKafkaReceiver.java#L58)) each `KafkaReceiver.receive` call would create single thread under the hood which would execute basic blocking `KafkaConsumer.poll()` [underneath](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/8436f5ca887898b3738df41deb973d1a58d5881e/src/main/java/reactor/kafka/receiver/internals/ConsumerEventLoop.java#L357). So it's actually doesn't matter so much whether do you use reactive receiver or raw Kafka consumer API, your question relates to basic Kafka topic management and configuration.

There are plenty articles on it, [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-choose-number-topics-partitions-kafka-cluster/) is the Confluent's one for example. In a nutshell, usually multiple partitions leads to a higher performance, but in practice it depends on where is the bottleneck of your solution.